# Programmatically remove duplicate row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has been truncated at one point and now has a number of collisions in the data.
For this post I've renamed the data attributes but the structure remains the same:

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| parts_total_id  | parts_id  | title      | text        | value     | class       |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|            3000 |      1001 | Sub-Total: | $2400       | 2400.0000 | part_subtotal |
|            3001 |      1001 | Discount:  | $0          |    0.0000 | part_discount |
|            3002 |      1001 | Total:     | $2400       | 2400.0000 | part_total    |
|            5001 |      1001 | Subtotal   | $3200.00    | 3200.00   | part_subtotal |
|            5002 |      1001 | Total      | $3200.00    | 3200.0000 | part_total    |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I am trying to remove the older records (3000, 3001, 3002) and can use the following to select the records I want to remove with class 'part_subtotal' and 'part_total' then move them to a table and run a delete based on the parts_total_id:

```
SELECT *
FROM parts_total
WHERE parts_total_id not in 
(
    SELECT max(parts_total_id)
    FROM parts_total
    WHERE class = 'part_total'
    GROUP BY parts_id
)
AND parts_total_id not in
(
    SELECT max(parts_total_id)
    FROM parts_total
    WHERE class = 'part_subtotal'
    GROUP BY parts_id
)
```

The issue I have is I also may need to remove record 3001 where it has the class 'part_discount' - this may not always be present but it is usually between part_subtotal and part_total.

Comment: Could you use `DELETE 
FROM parts_total
WHERE parts_total_id < (SELECT MAX(parts_total_id) 
                        FROM parts_total p1
                        WHERE p1.parts_id = parts_total.parts_id AND class = 'part_subtotal')` - working on the assumption that the first transaction for a given `parts_id` value is `part_subtotal`?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following with the comment from @Nick:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts_total_temp AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM parts_total
    WHERE parts_total_id not in 
    (
       SELECT max(parts_total_id)
       FROM parts_total
       WHERE class = 'part_total'
       GROUP BY parts_id
    )
    AND parts_total_id not in
    (
       SELECT max(parts_total_id)
       FROM parts_total
       WHERE class = 'part_subtotal'
       GROUP BY parts_id
    )
    AND parts_total_id < 
    (
       SELECT MAX(parts_total_id) 
       FROM parts_total p1 
       WHERE p1.parts_id = parts_total.parts_id 
       AND class = 'part_subtotal'
     )
);

DELETE pt1
FROM parts_total pt1
JOIN parts_total_temp pt2 ON pt1.parts_total_id = pt2.parts_total_id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS parts_total_temp;
```